# Angular Component not showing up

Tags: angular

I was working in an angular project but in some point it stopped showing, I looked for many answers but none worked. The Index.HTML file of the src folder is shown instead of the app-component.
My file app.module.ts is the next

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Punto1Component } from './components/punto1/punto1.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Punto1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
        
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Index.Html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TpAngular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app-component.html

`<app-punto1></app-punto1>`

My punto1.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Producto} from 'src/app/models/producto'
declare var window:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-punto1',
  templateUrl: './punto1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./punto1.component.css']
})
export class Punto1Component implements OnInit{
ngOninit(){ }
}
```

And Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "tpAngular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/tp-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "tpAngular:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "tpAngular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tpAngular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics":"bb100d1b-00a6-46a4-92b1-dcfb4b9da949"
  }
}
```

The app.component.ts is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tpAngular';
}
```

I tried many solutions that i found in this site and other websites as well, even created a new project, new port, with the ng serve --open command, etc.

Comment: can you please show what AppComponent ts and html file is like ?

Comment: I added the app.component.ts, the html was already in the post is just <app-punto1></app-punto1>

Answer (score 0):

Within your AppComponent template, be sure to bind your component:

```
<app-punto1></app-punto1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are getting compilation error because you have not implemented ngOninit();

```
export class Punto1Component implements OnInit{
     ngOninit(){ }
  }
```

Comment: I already had that in my code, but the component still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is related to your Angular environment. I guess there could be another web server which enabled the directory listing feature running. The server might be Microsoft IIS, Tomcat, or Apache... If that was the case, please turn the feature off.